# Python Smtplib WinError 100022

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email using Python and I used the material I found on the official site (https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) but I'm getting an error when sending an email. Using the port and server works when I use Java but when using the same details in Python the code doesn't work.

The code that I am testing:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

port = 25
server = "172.xxx.xxx.xxx"

from_add = "test@fakemail.com"
to_add = "test@fakemail.com"

message = "This is a test Email"
subject = "Test Email"

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(message)
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["From"] = from_add
msg["To"] = to_add

#Send the message via our own SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(server)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

When I run my code I get the below error. I have been searching the net and all I am finding are errors concerning sockets (I tried adding  which I haven't seen in any examples. My firewall admin tells me he doesn't see any traffic being blocked his end. Does anyone know if what I am coding is wrong?

Original

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/test/test_email.py", line 21, in <module>
    s = smtplib.SMTP(server)
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "X:\Enviroments_For_Python\PROD\lib\socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Socket change (didn't work)

```
s.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sock.bind(server, port)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I am using Anaconda and had created a different environment. When I switched to the root environment my code worked without a problem.